# How to use Apache Ignite spatial features via nodejs?

Tags: node.js, geospatial, ignite, jts

When using ignite as embedded database in Java, we can use spatial extension and JTS to make spatial queries possible. Now suppose we are using Ignite daemon as stand alone persistence, and we need to use its spatial capabilities. When geospatial extensions enabled, we must first create cache with geo types to be able to query the database. How can we use JSTS for this task?

For example, we can create a cache using this lines:

```
const cache = await igniteClient.getOrCreateCache('myCache');
    // set cache key/value types
    cache.setKeyType(ObjectType.PRIMITIVE_TYPE.INTEGER).
        setValueType(new MapObjectType(
            MapObjectType.MAP_SUBTYPE.LINKED_HASH_MAP,
            ObjectType.PRIMITIVE_TYPE.SHORT,
            ObjectType.PRIMITIVE_TYPE.BYTE_ARRAY));
```

As you can seer, types are simple primary types or hashmap types. What if I need to save e.g. Point values? Can we use JSTS? Is there any other method to use Binary protocol for this task?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Node.js Thin client](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/nodejs-thin-client).
It has support for running SQL queries on Ignite, and Ignite SQL has [geospatial support](https://apacheignite-sql.readme.io/docs/geospatial-support).

So, follow the documentation for geospatial SQL to learn how to use that, and then run the spatial SQL queries from Node.js.